# No output from PHP interactive on Windows

Tags: php, windows-7, command-line-interface, output

I'm running php interactively from xampp (5.4.7) on my Win 7 machine and cannot get any output from the window.  I searched around various solutions and nothing so far has worked.  Here's a sample:
    C:\xampp>php -v
    PHP 5.4.7 (cli) (built: Sep 12 2012 23:48:31)
    Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies

```
C:\xampp>php -a
Interactive mode enabled

<?
echo "hi";
printf "hi";
fwrite (STDOUT, "hi");
```

any other ideas???

I also tried php -an and setting output_buffing Off in the php.ini, all to no avail.

Basically my aim is mostly to use this as a testbed for php expressions as well as running some local scripts.

Answer (score 14):

The first line I type after entering `php -a` is slightly different to yours:

```
<?php          //press Enter
echo 'This ';  //press Enter
echo 'works';  //press Enter
//Press Ctrl+z on this line to get a ^Z, then press Enter
This works
C:\Windows\System32>
```

The nuisance is that it returns to the Windows command prompt and you have to keep typing **php -a** and **<?php** before you can type more.

To save a bit of typing I created a shortcut, right-clicked it, opened its Properties dialog and entered the following command in the ***Target*** text box:

> C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "php -a"

This shortcut opens a PHP prompt in interactive mode. Alternatively, this one starts in interactive mode and lists the PHP switches:

> C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "php -h & php -a"

Comment: Finally, something that works (on Windows 8.1) :) Thx

Answer (score 12):

`Interactive mode` is *not* the same as `Interactive shell`. The later accepts commands like in cmd or a shell found in linux. The first one reads in the **whole** script and then returns with the output. If you would hit `CTRL-Z` at the end of the snippet it should return the output.

Check here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php for more information (especially the [first comment](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php#108006)).

Comment: Thanks.  Ctrl-Z doesn't work, nor does ctrl-d as some suggest.  But that link sounds pretty discouraging for getting an interactive php in Windows.  Perhaps I need to go to Cygwin or such to do this?

Comment: I've tried PHPSH once in combination with Cygwin, it's from Facebook and uses some Python to make it work but it did work ok after some fiddeling. http://www.phpsh.org/

Comment: If you have **interactive mode**, make sure you type `<?php` at the start

Answer (score 11):

If you start "php -a" and see "Interactive **mode** enabled" instead of "Interactive **shell**", then your copy of php was likely compiled without readline support, and there is no interactive shell.

**As far as I know, Windows copies of PHP are all compiled without readline support. This makes the "-a" option worthless in Windows** (at least to me).

"php -a" is supposed to work like this (output from a linux copy of php in this case):

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > echo 5+8;
13
php > exit
$
```

"php -a" in a Windows copy of PHP is not an interactive shell, and so effectively works the same as leaving off the "-a" option. Use F6 or CTRL+Z to type the EOF character to finish the script (appears as ^Z):

```
C:\>php -a
Interactive mode enabled

<?php
echo 5+8;
?>
^Z
13
C:\>
```

Leave off the "-a" and you get essentially the same results (minus the text "Interactive mode enabled":

```
C:\>php
<?php
echo 5+8;
?>
^Z
13
C:\>
```

If you use "php -a" and get the text "Interactive mode enabled" and don't get the output for cli.prompt (usually "php >"), then you should check your php version (with "php -v") to make sure it is at least 5.1, and your php modules (with "php -m") to make sure the "readline" module is listed.

Comment: The problem with `php -a` is that it does not execute the commands until you terminate it with `ctrl+z`. The developer may need to extract further information.

Answer (score 2):

I make cmd script for emulate interactive php shell. It reads each command into an environment variable and then starts a new instance of PHP to run each command.

```
@echo off
:loop
    set /p php="php> " %=%
    php -r "%php%"
    echo.
goto loop
```

Comment: The problem with this is it will not remember variables or functions you define

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 7.1.0 both the [`interactive shell`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.interactive.php) and [`readline`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/readline.installation.php) are supported on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

To use in windows.  Ensure you have a PATH variable to php directly in your windows environment.  May require restart.  Use gitbash/cmd/rails shell/nodejs etc. but shouldn't make any difference.  Open cmd

Check php with command: 
    php -v
if all good populates the php version etc etc

load interactive mode with: 
    php -a
enter your code once enabled, for example as follows (each line has carriage return)
the ^z is the shell output of pressing the ctrl key and the z key together
this runs your small snippet but instantly pops you out of php interactive mode

```
<?php
$x = 5;
$y = 6;
$z = $x + $y;
echo $z;
?>
^z
```

(will return 11) was really good at maths ha:-)

Answer (score 0):

When using the `Interactive Mode`, you literally need to input the whole script.

```
<?php
echo "HELLO WORLD";
```

Then to "execute" the script, you need to do `CTRL+Z` on an empty line and press `ENTER`

Answer (score 0):

As you can read from the other answers, Windows PHP does not support echoing commands(easily).
On Windows 10 there is a way around this however, you can enable the Windows 10 Ubuntu sub-shell system.

#### To install windows-subsystem for linux

Do one of the following:

- Control Panel -> Apps -> Administrate optional features.
  Then make sure `Windows-subsystem for linux` is checked.
- You can also install it by running `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux` in an elevated Powershell Window.

Now reboot(maybe bookmark this page first)

Once you've rebooted install [this app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu/9nblggh4msv6) and open it.
When it's done loading and you've created your user, type `sudo apt update && apt upgrade && apt install PHP`.

Now when you need php interactive just open command prompt and type `bash` then `php -a`